# Два item в RecyclerView

Tags: android

RecyclerView отображает список. Нужно, что бы при одном условии отображался один item, а при другом - другой. Как это реализовать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использовать `getItemViewType()`. Например

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
class ViewHolder0 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ...
}

class ViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ...
}

private static final int TYPE_IMAGE = 0;
private static final int TYPE_GROUP = 1;

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    int viewType;
    if (groups.get ( position ).getImagePath () != null ) {
        viewType = TYPE_IMAGE;
    } else {
        viewType = TYPE_GROUP;
    }
    return viewType;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     switch (viewType) {
         case 0: return new ViewHolder0(...);
         case 2: return new ViewHolder2(...);
         ...
     }
}
}
```

Comment: А как в onBindViewHolder определять какой ViewHolder использовать?